# Make column from data

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
 order_id  user_id  lunch_type  box
   1          1        A         5
   2          1        B         1
   3          1        C         3
   4          2        C         4
   5          2        B         2
   6          3        A         7
   7          4        C         6
   8          4        A         1
   9          5        C         9
  10          5        B         2
```

From the tabel above, I want to make a new tabel like this

```
 user_id    Lunch_A   Lunch_B, Lunch_C   total
   1           5         1        3        9
   2           4         2        0        6
   3           7         0        0        7
```

I don't know how to query like that

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your exisinting table is Orders and new table is OrdersSummary, so you can create new table by :

```
CREATE TABLE OrdersSummary
AS ( SELECT 
        user_id, 
        count(*) as total,
        count(IF(lunch_type = "A", 1, NULL)) as Lunch_A,
        count(IF(lunch_type = "B", 1, NULL)) as Lunch_B,
        count(IF(lunch_type = "C", 1, NULL)) as Lunch_C  
    from Orders group by user_id 
   );
```

Explanation:

Creating table from another table using CREATE TABLE  as (Select columns from )

While selecting records from existing table we're grouping rows on the basis of user_id so count(*) will give use total count and we want to count of lunch_type (A, B, C) separately so in count expression we're using IF clause so it row has specific lunch_type only then it'll be counted